# How to save in fire and forget mode with spring 5 reactive repository

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming

I'm trying to figure how to make a save in (for example mongo) with a spring 5 ReactiveCrudRepository in fire and forget mode.

The code is simple

```
public Mono<MyObject> saveObject(Mono<MyObject> mono) {
    return mono.flatMap(objectRepository::save);
}
```

the fact is i don't need to read the returned Value, and in the reactive world, reading action trigger the save.

i have tried 
        objectService.saveObject(Mono.just(object)).block();
and it works just fine, but it's blocking :D

I wonder how to do it properly. (or if it is simply a bad idea)

thanks Julien

Answer (score 4):

```
objectService.saveObject(Mono.just(object)).subscribe();
```

You need an operation that will trigger the action. 
`.block()` is one way to do it, but it's a bad idea. Once you "block" you're not in the reactive world anymore.

If you're not interested in the value the is returned by the method - you can use and empty subscribe method - it will just trigger the action.

Even if I'm not interested in the value I would use the `Mono.subscribe(Consumer<? super Person> consumer, Consumer<? super Throwable> errorConsumer, Runnable completeConsumer)` overload just to log the outcome of the operation:

```
objectService.saveObject(Mono.just(object)).subscribe(null, 
                                                      error -> logger.error(error), 
                                                      () -> logger.info("completed"));
```